# Typescript Kendo ui mobile MVVM events beforeShow not firing

Tags: mobile, mvvm, kendo-ui, typescript

I am trying to implement MVVM event binding in typescript. The following is working for me in javascript:-
(except the click event??)

```
<div id="config" data-role="view" data-layout="default" data-title="Config" data-model="viewModelConfig"
     data-bind="click: onClick, events: { init: onViewInit, show: onViewShow, beforeShow: onBeforeShow }">
    <h2>Configuration!</h2>
</div> 

<script>
    var viewModelConfig;

    var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body,
    {
        platform: 'ios',
        hideAddressBar: true,
        initial: "home",
        transition: 'overlay:up',
        init: function () {

            viewModelConfig = kendo.observable({

                onClick: function (e) {
                    console.log("onClick");
                },

                onViewInit: function (e) {
                    console.log("ViewModel:onViewInit");
                },

                onViewShow: function (event) {
                    console.log("ViewModel:onViewShow");
                },

                onBeforeShow: function (event) {
                    console.log("ViewModel:onBeforeShow");
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Below is my typescript version and none of the events fire except click works?
What is going on here?

```
 <div id="config" data-role="view" data-layout="shared-layout" data-title="Config"
     data-bind="click: onClick, beforeShow: onBeforeShow, init: onViewInit, events: { show: onViewShow }">
    <h2>Configuration</h2>
</div>
```

...

```
require(['jquery', 'kendo', 'telerikReportViewer', 'app/AppMain'], ($, kendo, TRV, AppMain) => {
var viewModelConfig:any;

window.onerror = function (event: Event, source: string, fileno: number, columnNumber: number) {
    alert("Error:" + event.type + " source:" + source);
}

var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body,
    {
        icon: "Content/images/prpsolutions_logo.png",
        platform: 'ios',
        hideAddressBar: true,
        initial: "home",
        transition: 'overlay:up',
        init: function () {

            viewModelConfig = kendo.observable({

                onClick: function (e) {
                    console.log("viewModelConfig:onClick");
                },

                onViewInit: function (e) {
                    console.log("viewModelConfig:onViewInit");
                },
                onViewShow: function (event) {
                    console.log("viewModelConfig:onViewShow");
                },
                onBeforeShow: function (event) {
                    console.log("viewModelConfig:onBeforeShow");
                }
            });
            kendo.bind($("#config"), viewModelConfig, kendo.mobile.ui.View);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out.

In the case of Typescript I didn't know how to reference the viewModelConfig variable from HTML (required for MVVM data-model="viewModelConfig"). So resorted to manually binding (using kendo.bind($("#config"), viewModelConfig)) - which didnt work!

But if I delcare viewModelConfig inline externally to my startup function, the HTML can see the variable.

```
declare var viewModelConfig: any;

require(['jquery', 'kendo', 'telerikReportViewer', 'app/AppMain'], ($, kendo, TRV, AppMain) => {

var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body,
    {
        transition: 'overlay:up',
        init: function () {

            viewModelConfig = new kendo.observable({

                onClick: function (e) {
                    console.log("viewModelConfig:onClick");
                },

                onViewInit: function (e) {
                    console.log("viewModelConfig:onViewInit");
                },
                onViewShow: function (event) {
                    console.log("viewModelConfig:onViewShow");
                },
                onBeforeShow: function (event) {
                    console.log("viewModelConfig:onBeforeShow");
                }
            });
etc.
```

It now works.